# Hide div with jQuery (length option) not working

Tags: jquery, css, drupal

I'm using Drupal 7.0 and Galleria Javascript Image Gallery (fullscreen theme). And my theme got 2 navigation buttons. That's css code:

```
.galleria-image-nav {
  height: 159px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 65%;
  width: 82px;
  z-index: 11000;
}
```

I want when browser get 960px, this nav buttons hide with fadeout effect. And my js code:

```
if ( $(".galleria-image-nav").length > 0 ) {
  if ( w_width < 960 ) {
    $(".galleria-image-nav").fadeOut(400);
  } else {
    $(".galleria-image-nav").fadeIn(400);
  }
}
```

But this function not working. Whats problem? Thanks. (and sorry my English.)

Comment: how is w_width set? Is it getting browser width corectlly?

Comment: as @DzikiMarian said, it would be easier if you can post the function in which this 'if' resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ( $(".galleria-image-nav").length > 0 ) {
     if ( $(window).width() < 960 ) {
       $(".galleria-image-nav").fadeOut(400);
       }
     else {
       $(".galleria-image-nav").fadeIn(400);
       } 
     }
});​
```

Something like that should work